# How set preference `$ErrorView = "CategoryView"` before start powershell.exe

Tags: windows, powershell

How to set preference `$ErrorView = "CategoryView"` before start powershell.exe ?

`powershell.exe -command  "$ErrorView = "CategoryView" ; dir wrong.txt"` doesnt work.

Comment: set it in your $profile, I suppose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your code has a serious error in it. you used 4 double quotes instead of two on the outside and a pair of single quotes on the inside. [*grin*]

this works ...

```
powershell.exe -command  "$ErrorView = 'CategoryView' ; dir wrong.txt; pause"
```

remove the `pause` when you are certain things are working as needed. [*grin*]

Answer (score 0):

To complement [Lee Dailey's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55049276/45375): As Lee points out, your primary problem is that you **neglected to *escape* the `"` chars. *embedded* in your overall `"..."` command**.

Assuming that you're **calling your command from *outside* of PowerShell**, such as from `cmd.exe` (Command Prompt):

- Using **embedded *single*-quoting (`'...'`) in lieu of the embedded `"..."` is an option *in this case***, as shown in Lee's answer, because `CategoryView` is to be treated as a ***literal* string**.
  Using `'` for the embedded quoting conveniently **obviates the need for escaping.**
- However, in cases where the embedded string contains ***variable references* (e.g., `$var`) or *expressions* (e.g, `$(Get-Date)`), use of a double-quoted string (`"..."`) is a must**, because only double-quoted strings are *expandable* (interpolated). **Escaping the embedded `"` as `\"` is then a must**.

  - Note that, by contrast, *inside* PowerShell `"` chars. must be escaped as `` `" ``.

```
# From cmd.exe, for instance.
C:\>powershell.exe -command  "$ErrorView = \"CategoryView\"; dir wrong.txt"
```

---

If, for some reason, you must **invoke another PowerShell instance from *within* PowerShell, use a *script block*** (`{ ... }`), which also obviates the need for escaping (and better integrates with the calling session by returning *objects* from the invocation, not just *strings*).

```
# From Powershell.
PS> powershell.exe -command { $ErrorView = "CategoryView" ; dir wrong.txt }
```